# Error: Cannot find module 'indexof' in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use nodejs for a application, i am continuously getting the 
error: Cannot find module.

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'emitter'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nilesh/node/node-v0.10.32/prgm/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

i tried installing one, but the other comes up, and this is continuous. Is there something which can be done to this, i tried doing this 
npm install -g emitter,

it prints the path where it is present but it is not solving the issue.What could be the solution to this.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show the exact code where this occurs and the exact error message that displays so we may see what is actually going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

`var Emitter = require('events').EventEmitter` in your code

or

`npm install emitter` from the commandline.

I don't know why you're trying to install `indexof`, the error is about emitter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am saying that one after the other I am  getting this error of not found packages, Is there any way of completely downloading all packages.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the relevant code and your package.json?